# can we run 2 group parallel tasks using django canvas for celery tasks

Tags: django, parallel-processing, django-celery

like this I added in my celery.py

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def execute_analysis(id_=1):
    task1 = group(news_event_task.si(i) for i in range(10))
    task2 = group(parallel_task.si(i) for i in range(10))
 return chain(task1, task2)()
```

Comment: So what happened!

Comment: it is executing but blocking sometimes and takes too much time in the queue to start processing and executing tasks one after another

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you want to achieve. Is it optimizing? ( Depends on what news_even_task.si() / parallel_task.si() are doing ) .

Comment: news event task is running for news data from scrapping url
and the parallel task is executing when data is coming every fix interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**: You are calling too many functions(tasks) in same process sequentially so if any task (scrapping news data) gets blocked all other will keep waiting and might go in block state.

**Solution** : A better design would be to run news_event_task in delay and and with each news_event_task if you want to call parallel_task then both can be done in same process. So now all tasks will run in parallel ( Use celery [eventlet](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html) to achieve this).

Another approach could be send these tasks in queue (rather than keeping its sequence in memory) and then process each news_event_task one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your Help. I will try and implement this way

Comment: @prachikumrawat Did it help, its still coming under unanswered category.